# Unselect a selected date in CalendarView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, calendarview

Some of the shown dates in my calendar view shouldn't be selected. If some of them are pressed I show an AlertDialog that explains the reason why it cannot be selected.

I want to achieve that, apart from that alertDialog showing, the selected Date that has caused it to open automatically unselects.

In kotlin pseudocode, it would be something like this for my app.

```
calendar_view.onDateClickListener = { date ->
[...]
[Condition that shows AlertDialog with showDialog()];calendar_view.getLastSelectedDate().unSelect()
[...]
fun showDialog()
```

The functions I've declared to try to get the last selected day from calendar_view are made up, it's just so it's clear what my intention is.